# I want to export my Open Directory 'network directory' to text. How? dsexport and dscl do not work

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

I am running macOS Monterey 12.7.1 with Server.app (which provides OpenDirectory)

I want to use `dsexport` or `dscl` to export the LDAPv3 that contains my network users. But I'm running into many problems where I get 'usage' returns (and failure) while I follow the man page.

This works:

```
dsexport export.out /Local/Default dsRecTypeStandard:Users
```

This works:

```
dsexport --N export.out /Local/Default dsRecTypeStandard:Users
```

But I need the network directory, not the local one

This does not work:

```
dsexport --N export.out /LDAPv3/myserver.mydomain.tld dsRecTypeStandard:Users
dsexport: Node name wasn't found. (Node name wasn't found.)
```

This doesn't work:

```
dsexport --N -u diradmin export.out /LDAPv3/myserver.mydomain.tld dsRecTypeStandard:Users
usage: dsexport [--N] [-r record_list] [-e exclude_attributes]
                [-a address -u username [-p password]]
                output_file node_path record_type
```

I also tried dscl, with no more luck, e.g.:

```
root@server ~ # dscl -u diradmin myserver.mydomain.tld -readall /LDAPv3/myserver.mydomain.tld/Users RecordName
Password: 
readall: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

How do I actually export my LDAP so I can create an import for a new one (and finally move away from Server.app)? Note, this is a working and running Open Directory LDAP and other Macs on the premises use it for authentication.

Comment: I think on the master server, the domain will be bound as `/LDAPv3/127.0.0.1` -- try that instead of `/LDAPv3/myserver.mydomain.tld`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that works for dsexport, thanks. I wonder why the other doesn't work, though.